# Given $k$, can we find $n$ such that $d$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers, pell-type-equations

Given an odd positive integer $k$. Define $$d=16(k+1)^3(k+2)(n+1)^2+1$$ where $n$ is alos a positive integer.

My **question** is: Given $k$, can we find $n$ such that $d$ is a perfect square.

Comment: Where does this come from?  It would be better just to post the first and see if the techniques you see allow you to solve the others.

Comment: @RossMillikan: This is related to a dynamical system problem which is not important to state here.

Comment: I tried assuming that we could in fact write $d=p^2$. So $$p^2-1=(p-1)(p+1)=16(k+1)^3(k+2)(n+1)^2$$ Now since all numbers involved are integers, we must be able to split the RHS into two factors that differ by 2. I tried $$16(k+1)^3(k+2) + 2 = (n+1)^2$$ From here, simplify a bit further and you'll find that $$n = - 1 + \sqrt{16(k+1)^3(k+2) + 2}$$ So if we can prove that the expression in the radical is a perfect square, we can find n for any number. Also I believe writing k+1 = q will make things look a lot nicer. I don't know how to proceed though

Comment: $16(k+1)^3(k+2)$ is never a square since $$ (k+1)^2 < (k+1)(k+2) < (k+2)^2 $$  Thus you have an ordinary Pell equation, $x^2 -A y^2 = 1$  with $A$ not a square

Comment: Let $d=m^2$. Some first solutions $(k,m,n)$:`(1, 4801, 244), (1, 46099201, 2352489), (1, 442644523201, 22588608734), (3, 5374978561, 75117608), (3, 57780789062419261441, 807511075857161297), (5, 46873096812360001, 301361494218524), (5, 4394174409561746573589926449440001, 28251492988044782096244926437049), (7, 1572584048032918633353217, 5791587730988896551760), (9, 144220715637070429940775452568001, 343772642385433639988435123780), (11, 29517418827673438078737876988224112320001, 49235101895488198317754115696590031224)`

Comment: @DmitryEzhov  the smallest $m$ value for given $k$ is the (1,1) entry in the matrix power
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
2k+3& 2k^2 + 6k + 4 \\
2 & 2k+3
\end{array}
\right)^{2k+2}
$$

Comment: ?  k += 2; a=[2*k+3, 2*k^2 + 6*k + 4; 2, 2*k+3]; b= a^(2*k+2); b[1,1]
%74 = 4801   //////
?  k += 2; a=[2*k+3, 2*k^2 + 6*k + 4; 2, 2*k+3]; b= a^(2*k+2); b[1,1]
%75 = 5374978561   //////
?  k += 2; a=[2*k+3, 2*k^2 + 6*k + 4; 2, 2*k+3]; b= a^(2*k+2); b[1,1]
%76 = 46873096812360001   //////
?  k += 2; a=[2*k+3, 2*k^2 + 6*k + 4; 2, 2*k+3]; b= a^(2*k+2); b[1,1]
%77 = 1572584048032918633353217    ////// 
?  k += 2; a=[2*k+3, 2*k^2 + 6*k + 4; 2, 2*k+3]; b= a^(2*k+2); b[1,1]
%78 = 144220715637070429940775452568001

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$d=16(k+1)^3(k+2)(n+1)^2+1\tag{1}$$
Let $d=x^2, y=4(k+1)(n+1), N=(k+1)(k+2)$ then we get $x^2-Ny^2=1.$
This is a Pell equation.
According to [Pell equation wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pell%27s_equation),  all solutions of $x^2-Ny^2=1$ are given as follows.

$x_m+y_m\sqrt{N}=(x_1+y_1\sqrt{N})^m$

For instance, let $k=1$ then we get $x^2-6y^2=1.$
We get the solutions from the obvious solution $(x_1,y_1)=(5,2)$ with $m=1..9$ as follows.

```
            (k,x,y)
            (1,5,2)
            (1,49,20)
            (1,485,198)
            (1,4801,1960)
            (1,47525,19402)
            (1,470449,192060)
            (1,4656965,1901198)
            (1,46099201,18819920)
            (1,456335045,186298002)
```

Hence we get the solution $(x,y)=(4801,1960) \implies (k,d,n)=(1, 4801, 244).$
Similarly, we get $(k,d,n)=(1, 46099201, 2352489).$

Other solutions(smallest solution) are as follows.
These solutions have already been found by  Dmitry Ezhov and  Will Jagy.

$(k,d,n)$
$(3, 5374978561, 75117608)$
$(5, 46873096812360001, 301361494218524)$
$(7, 1572584048032918633353217, 5791587730988896551760)$
$(9, 144220715637070429940775452568001, 343772642385433639988435123780)$

Comment: I am asking if the formula: $x_m+y_m\sqrt{N}=(x_1+y_1\sqrt{N})^m$  holds for all $m$ or there is smoe $m$ not verifying it.

Comment: @Safwane Holds for all m.

Comment: I posted it as question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4175329/about-the-solutions-of-the-pell-equation

Comment: @Safwane This formula gives infinitely many integer solutions.

Comment: From a number field perspective, solving the equation $x^2-Ny^2=1$ is the same as determining the units (up to sign) in the ring of integers of $\mathbf{Q(\sqrt{N})}$. This is done, for example, via Minkowski theory, see Neukirch's Algebraic Number Theory Ch.1 Theorem 7.4. If one only allows positive signs this tells us, as in Tomita's answer, that there are $x_1,y_1$, such that all solutions to the equation are of the form $(x_1+y_1\sqrt{N})^m$. From this you find, as in the answer, your solutions to the original equation.